Adding Async to Certain Scripts in Header using SimpleHTMLDOM
I am trying to add async attribute to certain scripts in the header before they are run.  I believe Simple HTML DOM will allow me to do this.  I have this so far and see the scripts and the Match text for the ones I want to change, but the attribute isn't being added.
$html = file_get_html('index.php');
foreach($html->find('script') as $script) {
    $src = $script->src;
    echo "Src: ".$src."<br>";
    if ((strpos($src, "sweet") !== false) || (strpos($src, "stacks_page") !== false)) {
      echo "Match<br>";
      $script->setAttribute('async', true);
    }
}

The scripts seem to be unmodified, ie. w/o async attribute.
